# Question title lost on non-relevant edit

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, migration, title

I found the old [question](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6556/176217) (which happens to be mine) with the link to the migrated post. That's how it looked 30 minutes ago:

> [image: before edit]

After that I fixed a typo in a word and now it look like that:

> [image: after edit]

As you can see on [revisions page](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/6556/revisions) link remains the same, and the target post is still visible, but it seems that because the link actually refers to the original (migrated, and currently vanished) question, it's not parsed correctly to display post title instead of raw link.

Comment: Pretty sure this is by design. It probably relies on the title of the meta copy, which I suspect is deleted.

Comment: @Laurel that's exactly what I pointed out. But that DESIGN looks broken since the target post is available to everyone, hence title should be extracted from the link.